# Google Sheets IF function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to do some formatting of a Google Sheet but am stuck with this.

I have a formula **=IF(AY8="",0,400)** which sets a value of 400 when a cell to the left is filled.

I would like to add an additional condition, which, if the same cell, in this case **AY8** contains a letter **"c"**, then change value to **"0"** and color of the field to red.

Can this be done?

Comment: `=IF(OR(AY8="",AY8="c"),0,400)`?

Comment: Yes, sure, but I dont want AY to be = c, I need it to change value only if AY contains c. There will be numbers in that field, so if I add a letter c in front of numbers, then I need the value to change to 0 and color to red. If that makes sense.

Comment: `=IF(OR(AY8="",FIND("c",AY8)),0,400)` then. for the color you can add conditionnal formatting

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a solution and it does the job:

**=IF(AY8="", 0, IF(ISTEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(AY8, "c")), "cancelled",400))**